# Windows 7: Introduce commands for the run-command

Tags: windows-7, cygwin

Given Windows 7, you can press Win+R to open the command prompt.

How I introduce short cuts to execute commands? For example, I use Cygwin and would like to open a Cygwin terminal simpy by writing "terminal".

Comment: Hmm. Typing `terminal` works for me. It shows `Cygwin64 Terminal` as a match. I can select and press enter ...

Comment: I am talking about Win+R, not the search bar in the start menu. Does not work for me that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) create a System Program Alias at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Management\System Programs
```

[image]
To do this, navigate to the key and create a new "string variable" named whatever you want to type into "Run" (in your case, "terminal"):

---

2) create a registry key at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\terminal.exe
```

[image]

And within it, create a string variable called path with your command "C:\xxx\yyy\cgywin.exe terminal"

Once done, add the same path to the default item in the key.

- Start > Run > "Terminal"
- Terminal System Program references terminal.exe
- terminal.exe fires your command in the App Paths Key.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you know a reference that explains what those registry entries do? My desktop link passes the arguments " -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -".
Furthermore, the desktop link leads to the home directory, whereas the registry entry now leads to the drive C: